# Merge [okhttpclient] into [okhttp]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[okhttpclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/okhttpclient) has 154 questions, all of them are related to [OkHttp library](https://github.com/square/okhttp/).
In fact, `OkHttpClient` is [a class](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/master/okhttp/src/main/java/okhttp3/OkHttpClient.kt) in this library.

Someone added as an excerpt for the [okhttpclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/okhttpclient) tag:

> DO NOT USE THIS TAG! Please use [okhttp] instead

I think it was meant to be a message to encourage people to use [okhttp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/okhttp) tag, but instead I'm proposing to merge it or add it as a synonym.

Comment: I just wanted to voice support for this. I always feel like there are so many tags that just seem like duplicates, and I feel like it's a bigger issue than some realize.

Comment: Moderators realize, @FeaturedSpace. We're the ones you have to convince. We have a one-click ability to merge tags and/or create synonyms. But this is a potentially dangerous action, as it destructively rewrites history without leaving any traces. (Which is also its advantage: it is completely non-invasive and non-disruptive to the community.) So, we're cautious about when we do it. There needs to be a justification provided. In this case, it was pretty obvious to me, so I carried it out immediately.

Comment: Good. I suppose I'll post on here more often when I see two tags that need to be blatantly combined.